# Classes e atributes html com valores aleatórios?

Tags: html, css, gmail, atributos, preprocessador

Tenho observado que algumas aplicações, tais como gmail, facebook e instagram estão apresentando classes e atributos como valores aleatórios ou possa ser um padrão usado, pré-processador ou gerenciador.

Fiquei bastante curioso só que não consegui encontrar nada que explique isto. 
Alguém tem alguma informação?

```html
<div class="ajl aib aZ6 aji" aria-labelledby=":ic" role="navigation" style="height: 174px;"></div>

<div class="D E G-atb" gh="tm">
<div class="nH aqK"><div class="Cq aqL" gh="mtb">
   <div>
  <div class="G-tF">
     <div class="G-Ni J-J5-Ji">
         <div id=":2l" class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-Pm T-I-ax7 L3 J-JN-M-I" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-tooltip="Selecionar" aria-label="Selecionar" style="user-select: none;">

<div class="J-J5-Ji J-JN-M-I-Jm"> [...]
```

Comment: Sim, isso quem faz pode ser o `php`, ou no caso do `MVC C#`, a engine `Razor`, já notei em alguns lugares que fazem isso para que o `adblock` não consiga bloquear.

Comment: humm. Vou verificar. Tem algum nome específico para essa técnica? @MarcoGiovanni

Comment: Desconheço se existe um nome para isto.